# Start of string to have one X and not 2 X's

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to find a way of checking if a string starts with only one "X" but not 2 X's in a regular expression.

So I think I have tried

```
Regex.IsMatch(teststr, "^[^X]{1}?^[XX]");
Regex.IsMatch(teststr, "^[^X]{1}?");
Regex.IsMatch(teststr, "^[^X]{1}");
Regex.IsMatch(teststr, "^[^X]?");
```

The results should be, if string Starts with 1 X only then give me all except the ones that start with only 1 X. A string with 2 X's is allowed

Comment: Negative lookahead?

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: @Tanya https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a [negative lookahead](http://regexstorm.net/reference)?:

```
^X(?!X)
```

Basically the `(?!pattern)` part denotes a negative lookahead, which will fail your overall expression matching if the pattern in the lookahead fails.

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/W0DtE5/1)

Comment: Which is better, "^X(?!X)" or "^(?=^X(?!X))"

Comment: My one matches X when it's not followed by X. The other one Uses a positive lookahead to ensure that the first character is X, and then within that a negative lookahead to ensure that the next character isn't X. I'd say my one is simpler to achieve the same thing. Often with regex there are a few ways to achieve the same thing.  i usually opt for the most easy to read option in those cases.